# Second Order Difference Equation with Time Varying Parameter: $ x_{t+2}-2\beta x_{t+1}+\beta^2x_t = a\rho^t. $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations

I'm trying to solve the following linear difference equation

$$ x_{t+2}-2\beta x_{t+1}+\beta^2x_t = a\rho^t. $$

For $\rho=1$ the solution is

$$ x_t = \frac{a}{(1-\beta)^2} +c_1 \beta^t +c_2 t \beta^t. $$

What is the procedure to obtain the solution for $\rho \in (0,1)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have
$$x[t+2]-2\beta{x}[t+1]+\beta^{2}x[t]=a\rho^{t}$$
The solution is
$$x[t]=x_{h}[t]+x_{p}[t]$$
Where the homogeneous and particular solution satisfy
$$x_{h}[t+2]-2\beta{x}_{h}[t+1]+\beta^{2}x_{h}[t]=0$$
$$x_{p}[t+2]-2\beta{x}_{p}[t+1]+\beta^{2}x_{p}[t]=a\rho^{t}$$
You have already found the homogeneous solution ans it is
$$x_{h}[t]=c_{1}\beta^{t}+c_{2}t\beta^{t}$$
For the particular one, substitute
$$x_{p}=\alpha\rho^{t}$$
this gives
$$\alpha[\rho^{2}-2\beta\rho+\beta^{2}]=a$$
Thus
$$\alpha=\frac{a}{(\rho-\beta)^{2}}$$
and the solution to the entire reccurence is
$$x[t]=c_{1}\beta^{t}+c_{2}t\beta^{t}+\frac{a\rho^{t}}{(\rho-\beta)^{2}}$$

Comment: But how about when $\rho=\beta$ ?